# Why this relationship is wrong?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Im trying to do a many to many relationship, where many brand has many product types and also has many models. And many product types has many brands:

So this are my eloquent relationships:

Ptype.php:

```
    class Ptype extends Model
{
    public function marca(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Brand.php:

```
public function ptype(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ptype::class, 'ptype_id', 'id');
    }
```

Migrations:

brands_table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('modelName');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ptypes:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ptypes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('productType');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

This is the exact error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `axis`.`ptypes` (errno
> : 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `ptypes`
> add constraint `ptypes_brand_id_foreign` foreign key (`brand_id`) references `b
> rands` (`id`))

Comment: _"references \`b rands\` (\`id\`)"_... is that the actual error message? If so, seems you've got an errant whitespace character somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, check your migration files orders. As far as I see, they should be like this:

1. brands migration
2. models migration
3. ptypes migration

Also, you can use foreignId instead of foreign, references, etc.

```
$table->foreignId('brand_id')->constrained(‘brands’);
```

So, you can delete these;

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
$table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
```

Comment: I forgot to change the migrations order. The ptypes table was trying to migrate before brands table. Thank you